# Summation values for mesh topology

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any formula in Excel which gives the total sumation for the Z including the Z value as shown in below diagram:

[image]

The total summation for Z after adding its value is 28.

Which Excel formula will give me this total summation?

I will explain it by another way, assume the (A to Z) are sites and each site has number of cameras as mentioned in the diagram, by following the traffic in the diagram we have to calculate the total cameras which are going to the site D then continue the summation to get the total cameras for site Z which are coming from all sites which is Z= { D: (A+B+C)+(value of D)+X+Y+(value of Z) }. The scenario such like a tree form, and I hope to provide me the formula in Excel which give the total cameras for site Z which equals 28.

Comment: This is a duplicate as I remember the same or similar question was posted several months ago, What research have you done to answer the question? Perhaps you could use the `LET` formula and build a recursive function to navigate through the topology.

Comment: If you are asking if there alternative tools perhaps a database that allows hierarchical queries is a better solution ( for example: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html#GUID-0118DF1D-B9A9-41EB-8556-C6E7D6A5A84E)

Comment: Although not it's intended purpose, almost any basic accounting system will let you build the hierarchy you show with appropriate summation.

Answer (score 0):

It is disadvantageous that summing nodes also have their own values. It would be better if it was separated.
However, you can name each value and make a list of them and a list of summation nodes. The name of the summing node is preceded by the letter `S`. Each regular node is assigned a name and value, and the summing node is assigned a name and a formula.
**Caution**: A `_` character is added to the name `C`, due to the name requirements in Excel (the name `C` is reserved). Single-letter names are used (for simplicity), but the use of such names in formulas requires additional parentheses (to distinguish them from column names).

[image: Diagram]